# Refreshing Repository Cache in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I wanted to know if there is a way to refresh the Pentaho Repository cache using ant. We have a build setup to pull all the new reports/jobs etc from version control and update the pentaho solution. I'm just stuck at the last step of refreshing the Solution Repository Cache so that the newly updated/added reports/jobs ect could be used.

My last option was to refresh Pentaho webapp in Tomcat but it would have been really nice to have an ant job or a http request that could be made from ant to refresh the cache.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Srijith

Comment: you can definately call a webservice to refresh the cache. Just check what the url is that the link in PUC uses that and explore from there.

Comment: @Codek : i am facing some similar prob , my page is not getting loaded and it says "repository cache refresh failed " any help with that ???

Answer (score 0):

Look at this jira issue: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-7632
You can use this url to refresh cache repository.